# Genymotion with Virtualbox uninstall completely and reclaim hdd space

Tags: android-emulator, windows-10, virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion with VirtualBox on my windows 10 yesterday.

After installation, I created 3-4 emulators. The order was first I delete one emulator then I create a new one. And then I realize that that had space is not reducing.

So I deleted them all uninstalled the Genymotion and VirtualBox and removed all the files & folders it creates.

Before installation, I had 40+GB. Now I have 32+GB of space.

My assumption is that although the device is deleted, the harddrive file isn't?

Though I have checked everywhere for them.

Is there a special way to fully delete an emulator? (They are no longer listed in genymotion interface)

Please help me.